# how to pass parent instance to child class as a property in lambda select construction

Tags: c#, lambda

i am trying to create a model list by lambda select
and there are some nested models, and i want construct them in one time
but i don't know how to pass the parent instance to a child property when doing the construct

```
         SubCategories = cc.OrderBy(c => c.ProductCategory.Sequency)
            .Select(c => new ProductCatetoryListViewModel.Category()
            {
                Models = items.Where(i => i.ProductItem.CategoryID == c.CategoryID).GroupBy(i => i.ProductItem.Model)
                    .Select(mg => new ProductCatetoryListViewModel.Model
                    {
                        Name = mg.Key,
                        Products = mg.Select(i => i.ProductItem).OrderBy(i => i.Sequency).ToArray(),
                        //Category =  ???? i want this to be the newly constructed ProductCatetoryListViewModel.Category which owns this model list
                    }).ToArray(),
                Title = c.ProductCategory.Title,
                Name = c.Name,
            }).ToArray()
```

based on @Enigmativity's answer
the updated code works fine

```
 SubCategories = cc.OrderBy(c => c.ProductCategory.Sequency)
            .Select(c => new ProductCatetoryListViewModel.Category(items, c)
            {
                Title = c.ProductCategory.Title,
                Name = c.Name,
            }).ToArray()
```

the constructor is

```
public Category(ProductItemCultured[] items, ProductCategoryCultured c)
        {
            Models = items.Where(i => i.ProductItem.CategoryID == c.CategoryID).GroupBy(i => i.ProductItem.Model)
            .Select(mg => new Model
            {
                Name = mg.Key,
                Products = mg.Select(i => i.ProductItem).OrderBy(i => i.Sequency).ToArray(),
                Category = this,
            }).ToArray();

        }
```

Comment: You can't. You need to create a specific constructor for `ProductCatetoryListViewModel.Category()` to do it for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you for answering. i modify the codes to use a constructor, it works